# How to pass props using slots from parent to child -vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a parent component and a child component.
The parent component's template uses a slot so that one or more child components can be contained inside the parent.
The child component contains a prop called 'signal'.
I would like to be able to change data called 'parentVal' in the parent component so that the children's signal prop is updated with the parent's value.

This seems like it should be something simple, but I cannot figure out how to do this using slots: 
Here is a running example below:

```js
const MyParent = Vue.component('my-parent', {
  template: `<div>
               <h3>Parent's Children:</h3>
               <slot :signal="parentVal"></slot>
             </div>`,

  data: function() {
    return {
      parentVal: 'value of parent'
    }
  }
});

const MyChild = Vue.component('my-child', {
  template: '<h3>Showing child {{signal}}</h3>',
  props: ['signal']
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    MyParent,
    MyChild
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <my-parent>
    <my-child></my-child>
    <my-child></my-child>
  </my-parent>
</div>
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need to use a [scoped slot](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Scoped-Slots). You were almost there, I just added the template that creates the scope.

```html
  <my-parent>
    <template slot-scope="{signal}">
      <my-child :signal="signal"></my-child>
      <my-child :signal="signal"></my-child>
    </template>
  </my-parent>
```

Here is your code updated.

```js
const MyParent = Vue.component('my-parent', {
  template: `<div>
               <h3>Parent's Children:</h3>
               <slot :signal="parentVal"></slot>
             </div>`,

  data: function() {
    return {
      parentVal: 'value of parent'
    }
  }
});


const MyChild = Vue.component('my-child', {
  template: '<h3>Showing child {{signal}}</h3>',
  props: ['signal']
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    MyParent,
    MyChild
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <my-parent>
    <template slot-scope="{signal}">
      <my-child :signal="signal"></my-child>
      <my-child :signal="signal"></my-child>
    </template>
  </my-parent>
</div>
```

---

The [release of Vue 2.6](https://medium.com/the-vue-point/vue-2-6-released-66aa6c8e785e) introduces a unified `v-slot` directive which can be used for normal or scoped slots. In this case, since you're using the default, unnamed slot, the `signal` property can be accessed via `v-slot="{ signal }"`:

```html
  <my-parent>
    <template v-slot="{ signal }">
      <my-child :signal="signal"></my-child>
      <my-child :signal="signal"></my-child>
    </template>
  </my-parent>
```

Comment: lol and just yesterday Vue 2.6 added a [new slot syntax](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Named-Slots), which is what they'll support in v3. So in this case: `v-slot="{ signal }"`. Although `slot-scope` is still supported.

Comment: @thanksd if I'm reading that right the newer syntax is for naming a slot, not scoped slots?

Comment: @thanksd or they're combining both into a directive?

Comment: @thanksd Ah ok, I get it. I'll update the answer later tonight or you can go ahead if you want.  https://medium.com/the-vue-point/vue-2-6-released-66aa6c8e785e

Comment: Is there any way I can do this without having to write `v-slot` and `:signal` in the "app" file, but directly integrate it in the templates for `my-parent` and `my-child` that I only have to add the `signal` prop on the parent in my app, and my children have access to it automatically.

Comment: @mesqueeb for that usage the best option seems to use dependency injection, see https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Dependency-Injection

Comment: Note, if you have a bunch of props you want to pass down to the child, you can use the syntax `<SomeParent v-slot="props"><SomeChild v-bind="props"/></SomeParent>`. This is basically the equivalent of `<Component {...props} />` in React. I always forget the syntax for Vue.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this technique.

In this example.
Let assume a parent component wants to share prop foo with value bar.

Parent component

```
<parent>
    <template v-slot:default="slotProps">
        // You can access props as object slotObjects {foo"bar"}
        <p>{{slotProps.foo}}</p>
    </template>
<parent>
```

Child

```
<template>
    <div class="parent">
        <slot :foo="bar" />
    </div>
</template>
```

Got the idea from  [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=emi436qg9mg)

I hope it helped you accomplish your tasks.

Answer (score 1):

I added this code inside of `<v-data-table></v-data-table>`

```
<template
  v-for="slot in slots"
  v-slot:[`item.${slot}`]="{ item }"
>
  <slot
    :name="slot"
    :item="item"
  />
</template>
```

And I added a props called slots. When I call the component I send a slots like:

```
<my-custom-table-component :slots="['name']">

 <template v-slot:name="{ item }">
  {{ item.first_name + item.last_name}}
 </template>

</my-custom-table-component>
```