# How to make a components prop available to its slotted elements?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a structure like this:

```
<childs>
    <child>
        <ul>
          <li v-for="item in currentData">@{{ item.name }}</li>
        </ul>
    </child>
</childs>
```

In the `child` component, I have a data property `currentData`.

```
// Child.vue
data: {
    currentData: {}
}
```

For some reason, I am assigning value to this `currentData` prop, from the `childs` component (not from `child`).

```
// Childs.vue
child.currentData = data;
```

How do I make this `currentData` available to the slotted elements of `<child>`:

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="item in currentData">@{{ item.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

The template for Child.vue is like this:

```
<template> <div><slot></slot></div> </template>
```

I tried something like this:

```
<template> <div><slot :current-data="currentData"></slot></div> </template>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass props using slots from parent to child -vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45180114/how-to-pass-props-using-slots-from-parent-to-child-vuejs)

Comment: @ShubhamPatel The answer in that question does not solve my problem. I don't want to use `template` tag for each of my `child` components.

Answer (score 0):

I belive what you need is [**Scoped Slots**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots).

For that you should explicitly pass (in the slot declaration at the template) what props you want to make available to the `<slot>` "user".

E.g. say you want to make a `foo` property available to the slot users of `<child>` (assuming `childData` property existi in `<child>`). You would do:

```html
<!-- This is <child>'s template -->
<template> <div><slot :foo="childData"></slot></div> </template>
```

From that point on, whoever uses that `<child>` component can access that `foo` property by declaring `slot-scope`:

```html
<child>
  <ul slot-scope="slotProps">
    <li>{{ slotProps.foo }}</li>
  </ul>
</child>
```

Notice that the `slot-scope` is declared in the element that takes the place where the `<slot>` was.

**Full demo:**

```js
Vue.component('children', {
  template: '#children'
})

Vue.component('child', {
  template: '#child',
  data() {
    return {
      childData: "I am childData"
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>

<div id="app">
  <children>
    <child>
      <ul slot-scope="slotProps">
        <li>{{ slotProps.foo }}</li>
        <!-- <li v-for="item in currentData">@{{ item.name }}</li> -->
      </ul>
    </child>
  </children>
</div>

<template id="children">
  <div><slot></slot></div>
</template>
<template id="child">
  <div><slot :foo="childData"></slot></div>
</template>
```

> What if I wanted to add another element outside the `<ul>` element? Vue simply discards anything outside `slot-scope`.

This is not due to `slot-scope`, but to `<slot>`s in general.

Since `child` has only one `<slot>`, the first element you place within `<child>` is the one that will take the `slot`.

If you want to have multiple elements take the `slot`, you'll have to wrap them. E.g. in a `<div>`. But, if you don't want this wrapper element to be rendered, use a `<template>`. See demo below.

```js
Vue.component('children', {
  template: '#children'
})

Vue.component('child', {
  template: '#child',
  data() {
    return {
      childData: "I am childData"
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```css
.child { border: 1px solid red }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <children>
    <child>
      <template slot-scope="slotProps">
        <ul>
          <li>{{ slotProps.foo }}</li>
          <!-- <li v-for="item in currentData">@{{ item.name }}</li> -->
        </ul>
        <span>howdy</span>
      </template>
    </child>
  </children>
</div>

<template id="children">
  <div><slot></slot></div>
</template>
<template id="child">
  <div class="child"><slot :foo="childData"></slot></div>
</template>
```

Comment: What if I wanted to add another element outside the `<ul>` element? Vue simply discards anything outside slot-scope.

Comment: Your code does not run correctly when you run it. It returns "{{ slotProps.foo }}" instead of childData.

Comment: @JustinMeskan Fixed it by forcing vue@2